# The option AxesLabel of RegionPlot does not work?

Tags: plotting

I use Mathematica 11. I want to add labels to axes when I use the RegionPlot function. I read the help document of RegionPlot, it says, "RegionPlot has the same options as Graphics, ..." Then I go to see the help document of Graphics. There is an option AxesLabel seems may satisfy my requirement. However, after I type the following code in Mathematica 11:

```
RegionPlot[x^2 + y^3 < 1, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, AxesLabel -> {x, y}]
```

and press Shift+Enter, the output is

[image: The output of the aforementioned code.]

As you can see, there are no axes labels. Then I try the following code:

```
RegionPlot[x^2 + y^3 < 1, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, AxesLabel -> {"x", "y"}]
```

I get the same figure. Do you know where is the problem? Thank you in advance.

Comment: It's a `Frame` use `FameLabel`

Comment: The `RegionPlot` doesn't have `Axes`, but `Frame`s. Therefore, try using `FrameLabel` instead of `AxesLabel`.

Comment: To Bob and Karsten 7: Your comments work, thank you very much!

Comment: There are [examples in the documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RegionPlot.html#299525187) for that.

Comment: To Karsten 7: Thank you again!

Comment: If you check `Options[RegionPlot, Axes]` it returns `False`, the same is true for `Graphics`. Set it to `True` and then `AxesLabel` works fine.

Comment: @JackLaVigne Thank you for your comment!